# Como mantener las fila enfocada en el centro de la tabla HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angular, table, focus

Tengo una tabla cualquiera con 200 filas y cuando hago scroll down muy rapido con `ArrowDown` el focus de la fila sube mucho hacia arriba y aveces se pierde por que se queda muy arriba, necesito que cuando haga scroll down el focus se quede en el centro de la tabla cuando el foco vaya por el centro.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden ver en el GIF el focus no se queda en el centro, arriba o abajo. Necesito que se quede en el centro, obviamente cuando llegue ahi.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza el codigo lo tengo en la PC de la empresa donde trabajo, pero es muy simple, tengo un evento que escucha todo el tiempo lo que el usuario escribe y si presiona la tecla ArrowDown ejecuta algo mas o menos asi: ```document.getElementById(this.IDElement).focus()```

Comment: No existira alguna forma de hacerlo con CSS?

Comment: CSS Puro no, ese es el comportamiento por defecto del scroll y el focus. Tendrías que cambiar la posición del scroll cada vez que escuchas un evento de focus para que el scroll se centre donde quieres

Comment: Ya lo solucione, gracias. Justamente lo que dijiste era lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Explicare un poco de como funciona... el escucha el teclado todo el tiempo, cuando recibe que ejecutaron la tecla ArrowDown(40) o ArrowUp(38) primero no permite que se haga scroll down por default como hacen la mayoria de navegadores. Luego de eso obtiene el ID de la fila anterior y le suma o resta uno para que se posicione en la siguente o anterior fila, luego de eso le dice cual fila acabo de enfocar y tambien le si fue cuando se presiono la tecla "ArrowUp" o "ArrowDown". Ya hecho esto el metodo buscara la tabla y conseguira la cantidad de filas que tiene y tambien obtendra el alto de fila selecciona para poder usar ese alto en el scroll, luego de eso el metodo evalua y si cumple hara el scroll necesario.

```
 ngOnInit(){
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.keyCode==38){
    //subir
    e.preventDefault();
    let j: number = +this.IDRow;
    j--;
    document.getElementById(j.toString()).focus();
    this.centrarFoco(j, "up");
  } 


  if(e.keyCode==40){
    //bajar
    e.preventDefault();
    let j: number = +this.IDRow;
    j++;
    document.getElementById(j.toString()).focus();
    this.centrarFoco(j, "down");
  }
});

scroll = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
centrarFoco(fila, key, x = null){
 var table = (document.getElementById("id_tabla")) as HTMLTableElement;
 let rows = table.rows.length;
 let rowsR = rows - 20;
 let nfila = fila;
 let height = document.getElementById(fila.toString()).offsetHeight;
 if(nfila > 10 && key == "down"){
   document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, this.scroll);
   this.scroll+=height;
 }else if(nfila < rowsR && key == "up"){
   document.documentElement.scrollTo(0, this.scroll);
   this.scroll-=height;
 }

}
```

Se va a necesitar una tabla que contenga sus ID de forma ordenada.

```
<tbody *ngIf="search == 'active'">
                <tr *ngFor="let device of devicesF | tableFilter:searchText:['name', 'ip', 'cn', 'macadd', 'model', 'area', 'hostname']; let i = index;" 
                class="row-height" 
                (click)="getRow(device.macadd, device.hostname, device.name, device.model, device.area, device.ip, device.desc, device.ppanel, device._clientID, device.pport, device.swId, device.swport, device.cn)" [tabindex]="i">
                    <td style="padding-left: 10px; width: 12%;">{{device.macadd}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{device.ip}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 12%;">{{device.hostname}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 14%;">{{device.name}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 8%;">{{findMaker(device.makerid)}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 8%;">{{device.model}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 8%;">{{device.area}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 35px;">{{findPPanelName(device.ppid, currentClient)}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 55px;">{{device.pport}}</td>
                    <td style="padding-left: 15px; width: 40px;">{{findSwitchName(device.swId, currentClient)}}</td>
                    <td style="width: 70px; padding-left: 15px; text-align: center;">{{device.swport}}</td>
                    <td style="width:13%; padding-left: 30px;">{{device.cn}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
```

Y un metodo que obtenga su ID cuando cambie de fila:

```
getElementId(i, key = null){
 if(key == null){
  this.IDRow = i.toString();
 }else{
  //document.getElementById(i).autofocus;
  this.IDRow = i;
 }
}
```